# How to get user's logout time upon logging out in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, logging

I want to know how to get the time a user logged out of WordPress.
I tried to implement this but it does not capture the time of logout:

```
function user_last_login( $user_login, $user ){
  update_user_meta($user->ID, '_last_login', time());
}
add_action('wp_login', 'user_last_login', 10, 2);
```

Above code gives me the last login date.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.

```
function user_last_login( $user_login, $user ) {
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last_login', time() );
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'user_last_login', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: this does not save logout time but log in time

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp_logout` hook to save logout time.

```
function user_last_logout(){
  update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_last_logout', time() );
} 
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'user_last_logout', 1 );
```

This hook will excute just before logout.